# How to set targetFragment for a DialogFragment from a childFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parent-child, android-dialogfragment

Im posting this question since I haven't found any convenient answer or similar question here.

Here's my scenario: I have MainActivity that has a tabParentFragment that itself has a childFragment

```
MainActivity
------ TabParentFragment 
-------------  ChildFragment
```

From the childFragment, I try to call a DialogFragment and set its targetFragment but I get an error:

```
Fragment MyDialogFragment {481d668 ...} declared target fragment ChildFragment{70c2a81 #0 id=0x7f0900de android:switcher:2131296478:0} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
```

Here's how Im calling my MyDialogFragment within the ChildFragment:

```
MyDialogFragment mdialog = new MyDialogFragment();
mdialog.setTargetFragment(ChildFragment.this, 91);
mdialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "MYDFTAG");
```

And here's how Im calling ChildFragment from TabParentFragment:

```
TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
ChildFragment = new ChildFragment ();
adapter.addFragment(childFragment, "The Child");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
....
```

And here's how Im calling TabParentFragment from the MainActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
new TabParentFragment()).commit();
```

I spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong and I don't seem to make it to work. Can you help ?

Comment: if I set this TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); to TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()); it doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to show `MyDialogFragment`

```
MyDialogFragment mdialog = new MyDialogFragment();
mdialog.setTargetFragment(ChildFragment.this, 91);
mdialog.show(getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager(), "MYDFTAG");
```

Basically, when you setTargetFragment it will be check `MyDialogFragment` and your target fragment must be same FragmentManager

In this case I recommend you show `MyDialogFragment` by `getChildFragmentManager` of `ChildFragment`. No need `setTargetFragment` instead of call `targetFragment.onActivityResult` you can call directly by `parentFragment` inside `MyDialogFragment`

```
MyDialogFragment mdialog = new MyDialogFragment();
mdialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "MYDFTAG");
```

Declare method `sendResult(parameters)` inside `ChildFragment`, in `MyDialogFragment` you can call

```
((ChildFragment)getParentFragment()).sendResult(parameters)
```

Comment: MyDialogFragment mdialog = new MyDialogFragment();
mdialog.setTargetFragment(ChildFragment.this, 91);
mdialog.show(getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager(), "MYDFTAG"); This did the trick just fine when linked to onActivityResult to get results. Thank you